Why PyQGIS is not calculating the square root correctly in this expression
I have a shapefile with ~100 fields, the first ~50 fields are motion towards the east, and the last ~50 are motion towards the north. There are 50 fields because each represents a date. I want to calculate the displacement using a simple formula (d= sqrt((east * east)+(north * north)).
Below is a sample of the shapefile

As I need to repeat this at least 50 times I am using the Python script in QGIS to create and calculate the new fields.
I am using the following code:
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils, edit, QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsFields
from math import sqrt

# Get the active layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# FIELD NAMES
east = ["E20160131", "E20160229"]
north = ["N20160131", "N20160229"]
# NEW FIELD NAMES
new_mg =["mg20160131", "mg20160229"]

######
if layer:
    # Start editing the layer
    with edit(layer):
        for name, e, n in zip(new_mg, east, north):
            if not layer.fields().indexFromName(name) >= 0:
                layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(name, QVariant.Double)])
                layer.updateFields()
            
            # Define a mathematical expression to calculate field values
            expression = QgsExpression(f"sqrt(({e}*{e})+({n}*{n}))") 
            # Create a context to evaluate the expression
            context = QgsExpressionContext()
            context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
            
            
            # Initialize the expression with the context
            expression.prepare(context)
            
            # Evaluate the expression for each feature
            for feature in layer.getFeatures():
                context.setFeature(feature)
                value = expression.evaluate(context)
                #print(value)
                if expression.hasEvalError():
                    print(f"Error evaluating expression for feature {feature.id()}: {expression_text}")
                else:
                    # Set the calculated value to the respective field
                    feature[name] = value
                    layer.updateFeature(feature)
            
            print(f"Field '{name}' added and calculated successfully.")
else:
    print("Invalid layer.") '''

But this code only does sqrt(n*n), seems like the e value is 0. I tried to replace the expression in the code by f"sqrt(({e}*{e})+({e}*{e}))" and the result is 0, it should be a very small number (for the first row 0.033383162533427116) but not 0. I also did f"sqrt(({n}*{n})+({n}*{n}))" and it works.
I used the field calculator to calculate the field just for the first date and it works perfectly. Also, all the fields are double and real in the layer properties.
I am not sure why PyQGIS is not doing the correct operation.

It might be a rounding issue due to ASCII exponential notation storage within dBase..

I also thought it might be that. But I am doing a new test and I am trying just f"{e}*100", which should give results such as -2.3605460604839, but the result is still 0. When I do it with n (f"{n}*100") it works

Are you using an appropriate field type?

That's what you would get if you were displaying/storing that value as an integer

Yes, all the files are double and real as shown in the images. The field I am creating is double ( QVariant.Double line 17 in the code). When I do the operation with only n it works and saves the results as a double. Also, the field calculator does the operation fine.
